# Firestore dependency implementation causes (Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file) error

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use firebase firestore, but the problem is that whenever I import its dependency using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1'
```

and I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 78891 > 65536)
```

Keep in mind that:

- I'm only using two dependencies in my project which are `firebasae-analytics:17.2.0` and `firebase-firestore:21.1.1`
- the project still doesn't contain any code.
- I've previously used `firebase-firestore:12.0.1` and It worked fine.
- removing the dependency would solve the problem
- I can't enable multidex because I'm using min SDK 4.4

So I want to know two things. First, is it normal for a single dependency to have more methods than that allowed for a single dex file? and second, how can I solve this if I can't enable multidex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching about this problem for days, and reading in the documentation and other forums, I couldn't find any solution other than setting `minSdkVersion 21` and enabling multidex by adding `multiDexEnabled true` to the `defaultConfig` section in the gradle file.